# How to run gRPC microservice with nestjs in a docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grpc, nestjs

I'm setting up a Nest JS microservice with gRPC in a docker container. I have installed the grpc package from npm but when i start the container i get an error message that the "grpc package is missing" how do i make the package available in the container

I have tried to install the grpc package with the RUN command in the dockerfile but i keep getting the same error.

```
FROM node:10.15.3

WORKDIR /usr/src/app/auth

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
RUN npm install --save grpc

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3001
```

it works normally outside the container, but for some reason its not working when i run it in a container

Comment: How are you running the container?

Comment: @DavidMaze i'm using docker-compose.  this is the block for that particular service ```auth_service:
    container_name: auth-service
    restart: always
    command: npm run start:dev
    build: ./auth
    volumes: 
      - ./auth:/usr/src/app/auth    
    ports:
      - "3001:3001"```

Comment: you ever solved this?

Answer (score 2):

What worked for me was adding the

```
RUN npm rebuild grpc --force
```

after the npm install